# Amcharts: How to pass title in balloonFunction?

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amstock

I want to format the data before passing it would be shown as a tooltip. For this purpose I use `balloonFunction` and `compareGraphBalloonFunction`

```
        "stockGraphs": [
          {
            "id": "g1",
            "valueField": "value",
            "comparable": true,
            "compareField": "value",
            "balloonFunction": this.ballonRender,
            "compareGraphBalloonFunction": this.ballonRender,
            // This is works
            //"balloonText": [[title]]
            //"compareGraphBalloonText": [[title]]
          }]
```

But when I send a title as a parameter to my ballonRender function I can't find the property that shows the name of my graph among `title` object.

```
  ballonRender(title) {
    let sign = (title["percents"]["value"]>0) ? "+" : "-";
    let values = (title["values"]["value"]).toFixed(4)
    let percentage =  (title["percents"]["value"]).toFixed(2)
    let newTitle = 'Product <b>%s</b> (%s %s%)'.format(values, sign, percentage)
    return newTitle
  },
```

If I print `title` inside my `ballonRender` function I observe the following object.

```
category : Mon Oct 02 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (Гонконг, стандартное время) {}
dataContext : amCategoryIdField: "1506873600000"
dataContext : {__ob__: Observer}
date : Mon Oct 02 2017 08:00:00 GMT+0800 (Гонконг, стандартное время) {}
rawData : (5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
valueAbsHigh : 1.0477245421
valueAverage : 1.04665801056
valueClose : 1.0466455011
valueCount : 5
valueHigh : 1.0477245421
valueLow : 1.0451341501
valueOpen : 1.0451341501
valueSum : 5.2332900528
graph : {id: "g1", valueField: "value", comparable: true, compareField: "value", balloonFunction: ƒ, …}
index : 40
isNegative : false
percents : {value: 4.664550109999993, percents: 23.826681846132807, total: 339.27455273}
serialDataItem : {dataContext: {…}, category: Mon Oct 02 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (Гонконг, стандартное время), time: 1506873600000, axes: {…}, x: {…}}
values : {value: 1.0466455011, percents: 23.826681846132807, total: 4.3927455273}
x : 608
y : 359.7633884380001
```

I can't understand why `[[title]]` in `balloonText` works fine, but when I pass this parameter to the function I can't retrieve the graphs title.

Also I'm a bit confused about input parameters in `ballonFunction` in general. It wound be nice if you share a resource with explanation and best-practicies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The title comes from the [graph object](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/StockGraph#title) itself. In the stock chart's case, the graph inherits the title from the `dataSet`, but the same property is populated. All you have to do is access the graph object that is passed as a second parameter to the [`balloonFunction`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/StockGraph), which you don't have in your function currently, to get the title data:

```
    "balloonFunction": function(graphDataItem, graph) {  
      return "<u>" + graph.title + "</u>: <b>" + graphDataItem.values.value + "</b>";
    },
    "compareGraphBalloonFunction": function(graphDataItem, graph) {  
      return "<u>" + graph.title + "</u>: <b>" + graphDataItem.values.value + "</b>";
    }
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/a185685b3e53407f22ab298b6de74dc3?editors=0010)